# grunt.util.spawn doesn't give output

Tags: coffeescript, gruntjs

Grunt.util.spawn is not calling the done function. Here is the code. when the command gets executed from command prompt it is failing and throws an error message which is not captured in gruntjs..what is happening

```
module.exports = (grunt)->
grunt.initConfig
    concurrent:
        dev: ['watch']
    slim:
        dev:
            expand: true
            src:  'views'
            dest: 'views/'
    watch:
        slim:
            files: 'views/**.slim'
            tasks:['slim']

grunt.registerMultiTask 'slim', 'Server Slim Compiler', ->
    console.log 'In the slim'
    options = {}
    options.cmd = 'dirld'
    options.grunt = true
    console.log options
    grunt.util.spawn options, (err,res,cod)->
        console.log 'in the spawn'
        if err
            grunt.log.error err
        else
            grunt.log.oklns 'success'
            grunt.log.writeln res

grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-contrib-watch'
grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-concurrent'
grunt.registerTask 'default', ['concurrent:dev']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`grunt.util.spawn` is asynchronous so you need to make your `slim` task async. See: http://gruntjs.com/frequently-asked-questions#why-doesn-t-my-asynchronous-task-complete

```
grunt.registerMultiTask 'slim', 'Server Slim Compiler', ->
  done = @async()
  grunt.util.spawn options, (err,res,cod) ->
    done() # Im done, continue onto the next task
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Could not find this in the manual for the life of me.